# Ranking Pandas DataFrame Based on Closeness to a Specified Value

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, ranking

Apologies if this is a trivial task. I am very new to coding and Python and am learning as part of my dissertation.

I have a data frame and want to rank each column within it based on its closeness to a specified value, rather than an ascending or descending order.

I am working on a way to compare Running/Cycling routes. As part of this process I am trying to find how a query route compares to a target route  based on a few different attributes: Distance, Elevation Gain, Elevation Loss and Gradient. My resultant data frame, shows the error between the two routes in each attribute within the comparison (i.e. [the target route value - the query route value] / the target route value). The problem that I am currently facing is ranking these results. As a perfect match would be a value of 0, I want to rank the values based on their closeness to this.

The data frame to be ranked:

```
scores = pd.DataFrame({'distance':[0.15, 0.07, -0.09, 0], 'elevation_gain': 
        [-0.19,-8.39, -0.86, 0],'elevation_loss':[-3.73, -2.51, -0.16, 0], 
        'gradient': [0.12, 0.39, 2.77, 0]})
```

In this case, the 4th route is the query route, as such the result is a perfect match and should therefore be ranked 1st.
As there are negative values, I don't think, a descending ranking would be suitable.

what I am aiming for is:

```
ranks = pd.DataFrame({'distance':[4, 2, 3, 1], 'elevation_gain': [2,4, 3, 
      1],'elevation_loss':[4, 3, 2, 1], 'gradient': [2, 3, 4, 1]})
```

(Appologies I don't know how to visualise these data frames to make this easier to digest)

I could then create a new column, summing the ranks and the lowest score would indicate the best match.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: `scores.apply(pd.Series.rank)
`

Comment: @W-B could you give a bit of background to what you've done here? I tried implementing what you said but there seemed to be no effect at all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ranks = scores.abs().apply(pd.Series.rank).astype(int)
ranks
```

Output:

```
   distance  elevation_gain  elevation_loss  gradient
0         4               2               4         2
1         2               4               3         3
2         3               3               2         4
3         1               1               1         1
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! @ScottBoston Could I be a pain and ask for a bit of background to what you've written there. Specifically, what the ".apply(pd.series.rank)" is doing.

Comment: Sure.  df.apply basically a function to every column of that dataframe.  So, we are applying the rank method from pd.Series to every column of the dataframe.